# Legalities on summarizing the content of publishers and publishing to our app for readers

Tags: copyright, internet, legal-terms

We have built a technology which gets trending things happening on internet from publishers like techcrunch, bbc, time of India and many more leading publishers. Then it summarizes the content of the articles and made it available to our app users.

We are mentioning the original article link with it's publisher's name. I just want to know what can be the legalities in this scenario and after we commercialize the app for technology that we developed that does the mentioned job automatically?

Answer (score 1):

*"Summarizes the content of the articles and made it available to our app"* is called web scraping, and the legality depends on the Terms of Service of each service you want to scrape, i.e Techcrunch, BBC, The Times of India. Read them; such services may restrict scraping by automatic means because they retain [copyright (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright) on their content. Simply *mentioning the original article link with the publisher's name* may not release you from copyright liability or suffice for a [Fair use (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) defense.

Local/national copyright laws may also apply. Since you sound like a business, talk to a lawyer, since you may have considerable liability with a web scraping app.

Comment: We are getting content from their official RSS feeds not by scrapping their original websites.

Another question that Yahoo is doing the same thing but not summarization. Yahoo publishes the exact same content from different publishers into Yahoo news website.

eg. Facebook and Instagram test a 'do not disturb' feature
Original - https://www.engadget.com/2018/07/02/facebook-instagram-test-do-not-disturb/
Republish - https://finance.yahoo.com/news/facebook-instagram-test-apos-not-172000854.html

How their are doing this?

Comment: RSS feeds make no difference; it's still the same copyrighted content, just in a different format. Yahoo probably legal licensing agreements with the services they aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

The summaries you describe are probably a derivative works of the copyrighted original and subject to suit for copyright infringement.

While isolated summaries of news may amount to fair use, automated, systematic summaries of a large share of the news content of a source for profit is probably not fair use.