# I plan on making an intentionally fake news site - can I *copy* headlines from other sources?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

First off: this is an experiment with AI - the content I create will state that it is fake and generated news - I'm not trying to mislead anyone!

So for my 'fake news' site I plan on copying headlines from news sites all over the web (using RSS feeds if that matters). **Is this considered *fair use*?** I have no issue with attributing where I get each headline (eg. A line below the headline saying something like 'source:www.bbc.co.uk'). I *could* generate the headlines myself, but I feel using real headlines adds an air of realism to the project.

If it matters, I don't expect to make any money from this, although there may be potential to make add revenue if it's a big success!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Legalities on summarizing the content of publishers and publishing to our app for readers](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/legalities-on-summarizing-the-content-of-publishers-and-publishing-to-our-app-fo)

Comment: Try https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=web+scrape

Comment: *I'm not trying to mislead anyone!* Well, mixing fake and actual news is likely to have the opposite effect, isn't it?

Comment: @SJuan76 the content I create is going to quite clearly state it's generated using an AI. I have 0 intention of trying to mislead anyone to the effect that I will probably go overkill with the disclaimers! This is purely an exercise in what I can do with AI (along with other programming tasks)!

Comment: where is your website located? Add a jurisdiction please, some countries make any misinformation punishable.

Comment: @Trish I'm based in the UK, and I'm now actually considering using a 3rd party website to post on to.

Answer (score 3):

To examine this further and answer your question, we need to look at Copyright (and fair use) as well as Defamation.

Alas, I am unsure as to how taking legitimate headlines from around the world and attributing their source is 'fake news' - but I'll accept that it's 'fake news' for the purposes of exploring this topic.

A lot of the potential (or motive) for a person or company to litigate against you will be context specific and detailed to how you have used their work and portray their journalists and characters - misquotes etc.

> As an exception to British copyright law, fair dealing is governed by
> Sections 29 and 30 of the Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988,
> which outlines three instance where fair dealing is a legitimate
> defence:
>
> 1. If the use is for the purposes of research or private study;
> 2. If it is used for the purposes of criticism, review or quotation;
> 3. Where it is utilised for the purposes of reporting current events (this does
>    not apply to photographs)

However, where you may come into problems is:

> A statutory definition for fair dealing does not exist; it will always
> be a matter of fact, degree and interpretation in every fair use case.
> Nor is there a percentage or quantitative measure to determine fair
> dealing. The Intellectual Property Office lists the key factors used
> to determine the validity of whether a particular dealing with a work
> is fair as follows:
>
> - Has the use of the work impacted negatively on the market for the original work? If the creator or owner has lost potential revenue through the re-use of their work, it is not likely to be fair.
> - Was it reasonable and necessary to use the amount of work that was    taken?

Also:

> Fair use for parody, caricature or pastiche The UK copyright law on
> fair use of works for the purposes of creating a parody or pastiche is
> also listed in Section 30A, Schedule 2 (2A) of the Copyright, Designs
> and Patents Act 1988.

References to all [here](https://www.bl.uk/business-and-ip-centre/articles/fair-use-copyright-explained).

> Guidance from the Intellectual Property Office (IPO) states that fair
> use needs to be “fair and proportionate” and does not protect an
> individual from any **other rights** an author may have.

Those **other rights** may involve claiming **defamation** if this material creates fake news and uses the names of real journalists or companies etc - and if they allege that your AI fake news has caused serious harm in any way to their reputation - they could sue you for breach of the [Defamation Act 2013](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2013/26). All of this is entirely contextual however as to how your AI might display or make fake news and how Google caches it and displays it - and if it could be portrayed as 'real' or believable for example.

You are also doing this at a time where 'anti fake news' law is evolving... and even though you say it's fake news for AI experiment purposes - it's a growing field of concern for many. (see [here](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/fake-news-laws-may-catch-during-coronavirus))

Copyright law is a vast and evolving area - and nothing is clear cut. It really depends if a major news company didn't like what you were doing and took exception to it and issued challenges on many areas of law based on that.